# How to visually recognize the checked menu item when using icons?

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-2007, popupmenu

I'm using a `TPopupMenu` component with icons assigned to its menu items (`TMenuItem`).

At designtime, the icons are not showed and the checkmark allows to detect which is the checked item:

[image]

At runtime, the icons are displayed but all items are drawn in the same way and I can't recognize the checked one:

[image]

How to visually recognize the checked item when using icons?

Comment: Any item can be checked, iterate and ask for item's `Checked` property.

Comment: @Victoria: Yes, I've updated the question by specifying "visually recognize". I mean that user can't discern between a checked and an unchecked item.

Comment: This is by design. If you have a group of items that can be checked, they should not have icons.

Answer (score 1):

To recognize visually your checked items at runtime, you'll have to customize their drawing at designtime.

If you have this opportunity, set your `TPopupMenu.OwnerDraw` property to `True`. Then for each concerned `TMenuItem`, you'll have to write a behavior for its `OnDrawItem` event. For example the code below (quickly written and not robust at all) can handle every TMenuItem render in a single method:

```
procedure TForm1.MyMenuItemDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  _item: TMenuItem;
const
  MARGIN = 4;
  INDEX_CHECKMARK = 3; // Add a checkmark image in your TImageList
begin
  // Get current item
  _item := (Sender as TMenuItem); 

  // Set then fill background color depending on selected state
  if Selected then
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clGreen
  else
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clMenu;
  ACanvas.FillRect(ARect);

  ARect.Left := MARGIN;

  // Draw a mark if item is checked
  if _item.Checked then
    AnImageList.Draw(ACanvas, ARect.Left, ARect.Top + 2, INDEX_CHECKMARK);

  // Inflate left position even for unchecked items, to keep text left alignement
  ARect.Left := ARect.Left + AnImageList.Width + MARGIN;

  // Draw image if available
  if _item.ImageIndex <> -1 then
    AnImageList.Draw(ACanvas, ARect.Left, ARect.Top + 2, _item.ImageIndex);

  ARect.Left := ARect.Left + AnImageList.Width + MARGIN;

  // Draw caption
  DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, PChar(_item.Caption), -1, ARect, DT_LEFT or DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP);
end;
```

I guess that instead of using a custom image for your checkmark there are some system methods, a quick search brings me to the following MSDN page which mentions `DrawCheck`: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Using_Custom_Check_Mark_Bitmaps